# Автоматическое позиционирование для JavaScript API

Tags: yandex-maps-api

В Static API Яндекс Карт есть [автоматическое позиционирование](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/staticapi/doc/1.x/dg/concepts/map_auto_position.html)

Можно не указывать масштаб, координаты центра или координаты углов. Параметры подберутся для лучшего отображения меток и многоугольников на карте.

*Вопрос:* как реализовать автоматическое позиционирование в JavaScript API? Удалив координаты и zoom в [примере](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark) с метками получаю отсутствие карты

Из

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
        center: [55.76, 37.64],
        zoom: 10
    }
```

в

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не надо создавать карту в пустоту. Она это не любит. =)

Если вам нужно определить зону карты по добавленным на неё объектам, просто создайте карту с любыми координатами и зумом, а после добавления на неё всех нужных объектов выполните:

```
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
```

Это и получится автопозиционирование.